# GitHub for Django on Azure: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

Tags: django, azure, github-actions, requirements.txt

I am trying to deploy my Django code to Azure with GitHub actions. On GitHub actions I keep receiving the following error message:

[image]

However, I have included a requirements.txt file in my project.

[image]

I have tried moving the file to different folders, since GitHub actions does not seem to be able to find the file, but that does not resolve my issue. How can I see where Github actions is looking for my requirements, or does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move it under the same level of .github folder