# GitHub Action Error: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt' while deploying on Azure App Service

Tags: python, django, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, requirements.txt

I built a simple **Django** application and am trying to deploy it using **Azure App Service** and **GitHub Actions CI/CD**. While deploying, I am getting the error-
[image]
Here is my project directory structure-
[image]
Can somebody please help me understand what the issue is here? I came accross this answer but this is not working for me- [GitHub for Django on Azure: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74067023/github-for-django-on-azure-could-not-open-requirements-file-errno-2-no-such)

Comment: Typo: in your repo you have `requirement.txt` but in workflow you using `requirements.txt` i.e. `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As @*Azeem* and @*aknosis* mentioned, the file name should be `requirements.txt` but you have `requirement.txt`.  Because the command you are using is `pip install requirements.txt`.
- If you still face the error, check if you still have `requirements.txt` in `Library_Management_System` folder and delete if the file exists.

I was getting the same error when I tried to deploy my Django application.

As per my observation, I had `requirements.txt` file inside the ***mysite project folder*** instead of ***Root*** folder of my application. Hence, I was not able to deploy my app to Azure.

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**GitHub:**

[image]

Later, I removed `requirements.txt` file from `mysite` ***project*** folder and moved it to ***Root*** folder of the repository.

[image]

***Deployment:***

I could deploy Django application to Azure App Service as shown below:

[image]

[image]